# react query call only when submit function is called

Tags: react-query

How can I disable react query from requesting the API before the searchEmployee is called?

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<EmployeeType>({
        id: 0,
        name: ""
    })

    const {
        isLoading, isError, isSuccess, data : employees, error, refetch
    } = useQuery({ queryKey: ['employees', value], queryFn: () => fetchEmployee(value) })

    const searchEmployee = ((params: any) => {
         const value: EmployeeType = {
            id: params.ic,
            name: params.passport
         }
         setValue(value)   
    })
```

Comment: you can use `enabled` prop in query options to disable the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best solution in your case would be to disable the query while the `id` is `0`

So therefore

```js
    const {
        isLoading, isError, isSuccess, data : employees, error, refetch
    } = useQuery(['employees', value],() => fetchEmployee(value), { enabled: value.id !== 0 } 
    )
```

This assuming that the `id` will change from `0` when the `searchEmploye` is done

Comment: options not found

Comment: what version of react query are you using @Alvin

Comment: "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.24.10",

Comment: the `useQuery` fn has 3 arguments. The query key, the query fn and the query options. The enabled is in the 3rd one

Comment: but the id can be 0 when user submit the form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252197/discussion-between-sabbin-and-alvin).

Answer (score 1):

To disable React Query from automatically requesting the API before the `searchEmployee` function is called, you can pass in the `enabled` option with a value of `false` to your `useQuery` hook. This will prevent React Query from automatically fetching data from the API when the component mounts.

```
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';

function EmployeeSearchForm({ searchEmployee }) {
  const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery('employeeData', searchEmployee, {
    enabled: false, // disable automatic fetching
  });

  // rest of component code
}
```

Comment: Not action after submit